# Problem with sending and receiving in streams C# in textbox Windows Forms app

Tags: c#, forms, textbox, streamreader, streamwriter

I managed to create a client server that communicate through forms.

I am able to display fist waiting and accepted messages.

My problem is when I'm writing to the stream and reading it on the other side the forms.

Here is where the sending and receiving happens on both programs:

Server-side code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace serverApp
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
        private static int connections = 0;
   
        public Form1() { }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void CreateServer()
        {
            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, 
                ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
            server.Bind(localEP);
            server.Listen(10);

            serverTxtbox.AppendText("waiting for a client");

            BackgroundWorker worker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker1.RunWorkerAsync(handlingFunction(server));
        }

        public object handlingFunction(Socket server)
        {
            while (true)
            { 
                try
                {
                    Socket client = server.Accept();
                   
                    NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(client);
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ns);
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ns);
                    connections++;
                    serverTxtbox.AppendText("New client accepted:  active connections 
                                 ${connections}");
                    writer.WriteLine("Welcome to my server");
                    writer.Flush();
                    string input;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        input = reader.ReadLine();

                        if (input.Length == 0 || input.ToLower() == "exit")
                            break;

                        serverTxtbox.AppendText(input);

                        writer.WriteLine(input);
                        writer.Flush();
                    } //end of while 

                    ns.Close();
                    //client.Close();
                    //connections--;
                    Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected: {0} active  connections", 
                    connections);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    connections--;
                    Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected: {0} active   connections", connections);
                } //end of catch block
            } // end of HandleConnection function 
        
        private void serverTxtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serverTxtbox.Clear();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            //start button
            try
            {
                CreateServer();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                serverTxtbox.AppendText("Connection failed ..");
            }
            //client.Close();
            //server.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Client-side code:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace app
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Socket client;
        NetworkStream stream;
        StreamReader reader;
        StreamWriter writer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void sendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
            // writing to the server
            handlfun();
        }    

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private object ConnectionToServer(Socket client, IPEndPoint remoteEP)
        {
            //client.Connect(remoteEP);

            try
            {
                client.Connect(remoteEP);
                clientTextbox.Text = "Enter Message for Server <Enter to  Stop >: ";
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                clientTextbox.AppendText("Unable to  connect to server. ");
                // clientTextbox.AppendText("e");

            }

            return client;
            // Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            // Client.Close();
        }

        private void connectbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9050);
            BackgroundWorker worker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker1.RunWorkerAsync(ConnectionToServer(client, remoteEP));         
        }

        public void handlfun()
        {
            stream = new NetworkStream(client);
            reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

            String input = clientTextbox.Text;
            writer.WriteLine(input);
            //clientTextbox.Text = input;
            //  String input = reader.ReadLine();

            writer.Flush();
            String line = null;

            while (true)
            {
                clientTextbox.Text = "Enter Message for Server <Enter to  Stop >: ";
                line = clientTextbox.Text;
                writer.WriteLine(line);
                writer.Flush();
                if (line.Length != 0)
                {
                    line = "Echo: " + reader.ReadLine();
                    clientTextbox.Text = line;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your actual problem here? Are you getting an error message? An exception? A compiler message? What would your ideal program execution look like? What is expected?

Comment: my problem is the the "clientTxtbox" " servertxtbox" are not showing what i am typing to each other .. like a chat sending a msg from clienttxtbox and displying it on the servertxtbox and the other way around

Comment: its on the writer its always null

Comment: That's not the way to use a BackgroundWorker. While it's possible to pass a function to RunWorkerAsync(), that's a blocking call.